# Which has the most updated Gnome-Shell: Gnome Remix 12.10 or Ubuntu Gnome 13.04?

Tags: gnome

I am thinking about replacing regular Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop with 13.04 Gnome - or Gnome Remix 12.10, given that the latter oddly has a longer life cycle as of now. Which of the two comes with the more updated state of Gnome, out of the box?
If the version numbers of Gnome are the same in both, are there any other differences to the Gnome-Shell experience?
More specifically, I am hoping for the customizations (shell extensions, user themes) to become more integrated and well-supported OOTB as development proceeds.
Currently, shell extensions are unofficial self-fixes that may or may not work with different versions of Gnome 3. To be able to use them, one has to install a package that isn't easy to find. Similarly, the ability to choose user themes is tied to an unofficial shell extension.
That is the kind of things I hope to see improved in the future, possibly even between these 2 versions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.04 is more updated, though not significantly once all updates are installed.  "Out-of-the-box" the Gnome remix has some big bugs in it that aren't fixed until the first `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

The big difference is that by adding the Gnome 3 PPAs to 13.04, you can upgrade to Gnome 3.8.  To my knowledge this does not work on 12.10 unless you add the `testing` and/or `staging` PPAs, which is risky if you care about stability.

As a user of Gnome 12.10 Remix, go with 13.04 and add the PPAs.  You'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu GNOME is formerly known as Ubuntu GNOME Remix and is the official gnome shell flavor of ubuntu.
Refer to [wiki here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME)

Latest Ubuntu GNOME/Gnome Remix version is 12.10 but 13.04 Gnome Remix is around corner, and it can be upgraded into Gnome 3.8 through [PPAs](http://worldofgnome.org/gnome-3-8-on-ubuntu-13-04/)

[UPDATE!] To get most updated Gnome-Shell, get latest Ubuntu version and upgrade gnome manually through PPA.  You can see from GNOME3 Team [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) the supported Gnome version by different Ubuntu versions

Ubuntu 13.04 --> Gnome 3.8

Ubuntu 12.10 --> Gnome 3.6

Ubuntu 12.04 --> Gnome 3.4

Comment: You're sort of repaeating what I already wrote, except for that last bit. I knew that both have Gnome 3.6 by default,  but my question is about which is more updated.